# Can't mount any partitions - ACL error

Tags: mount, acl

I've install Ubuntu 12.10 and now I can't mount any partitions.

I get the same error with drives: `Adding read ACL for uid 1000 to /media/proach failed: Operation not supported`

Comment: It seems to be a bug, as reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1048059

Comment: "proach" from "/media/proach" being Konstantin's user name..

Answer (score 20):

I have one word for this 'bug': fun. :)
I saw exactly the same error message today, and the solution is...

```
sudo mkdir /media/$USER
sudo chown $USER:$USER /media/$USER
```

(thank jasmines for the tipp!)

I know, fun, but that was the solution for me! Ubuntu wants to use a non-existent directory for the mount target, and doesn't create it before attempting the mounting operation!

Comment: Better `sudo chown USERNAME.USERNAME /media/USERNAME`. Please, edit your answer so I can award the bounty!

Answer (score 5):

Just follow these instructions:

```
sudo blkid
sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab
```

and fill information= in the appropriate pattern. For example, mine was:

```
UUID=445F-4D4E /home/str007/kortele vfat errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

My file now looks like this

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=69ede51f-a51e-4493-9c86-e553f952b3e6 / ext2    errors=remount-ro 0   1
UUID=445F-4D4E /home/str007/kortele vfat errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a directory in `/media` with my user name and with read-write privileges for me.  This worked OK, since I'm the only user on this computer, but it would be a pain with more users or changing users.

Answer (score 1):

As @jasmines points out it's a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/+bug/1048059).  The ACL change is not really needed to mount, but it's attempted if the directory doesn't exist.

- As others point out, you can just create /mount/$USER.
- The error happens when your root filesystem doesn't support acl. You can enable acl support by editing /etc/fstab (see details in bug).
- The final fix was just not touching ACLs if unsupported.
  You can get this fix it by installing udisks2 from quantal-proposed.  [Enabling proposed](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed) will offer you tons of upgrades; it's simpler to just install the [.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/2.0.0-1ubuntu1/+build/4023153/+files/udisks2_2.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb).

Answer (score 1):

the suggestion to mkdir + chown is right!
For absolute beginners, the following command will tell you your username

```
whoami
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with both a usb device and my primary (windows) partition. I managed to mount my windows partition by opening the "disks" application, selecting my primary partition, clicking "more actions..." (just below partition)  >> "edit mount options" >> and beside "Identify as" I selected `/dev/sda1`.

This allow me to mount my windows partition but it didn’t work for my usb device

Answer (score 0):

You can mount manually of course by: `sudo mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt/mountpoint`. I know it'a pain compared to 12.04...but it works.

Answer (score -1):

The last answer make a solution in some cases...

I just found a solution 100% effective. Follow my instructions:

**1) In a console write that: $ sudo gedit /etc/fstab**

**2) Enter your admin password**

**3) In the gedit Editor, go to the end of the file and write your data with this structure:
 #Hard Drive n1  the next line auto-mont the partition sda2 in the /media directory
/dev/sda2 /media/myHardDrive ntfs defaults 00
 #For CD/DVD the next line auto-mont the CD/DVD in /media dictory with the type iso966
/dev/sr0 /media/CD-DVD iso966**

**4)save the current text and close de gedit editor.**

If all of this works, when you insert a DVD, Hard Drive or any device, they will auto-mount in the directory that you put in the /etc/fstab file.

Of course, **if you are any question or error in the steps, i will write as soon i can.**