# Can't access any storage devices on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, usb, storage

Hi I've just started using Ubuntu 12.10 (today!) my first time with any non-windows OS. I wanted to retrieve some files after windows stopped working. I boot Ubuntu from a USB and it seems to work fine - I can access the internet etc. But I can't access any of my drives or even a USB drive. The error I get is 
"Adding read ACL for uid 999 to `/media/ubuntu' failed: Operation not supported"

Any help much appreciated:)

Comment: It should automount USB pendrives fine, and hard drives on the computer should be accessible from Nautilus (the file manager) Let us see what the system thinks it has. Insert a USB pendrive and paste the output from the command "blkid && sudo fdisk -l" into your question. (you can open a terminal with with <Ctrl><Alt><t>)  Congratulations on your move to free and open source software.  You are in for a difficult transition but once adjusted you will _never_ go back.  BTW you can paste the above command by marking it with the mouse and <Ctrl><c> to copy, then middle mouse button to paste.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your suggestion. I actually tried the tip given here http://askubuntu.com/questions/202630/cant-mount-any-partition-acl-error which seems to work for now. I'm going to try to install properly now, not just off the liveusb

Answer (score 0):

I too have been facing the same problem until coming to the link below.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks2/2.0.0-1ubuntu1/+build/4023153/+files/udisks2_2.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb

The above address is actually one single line (i.e. no space/new line between +files and /udisks2_2.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb)

After downloading the .deb in firefox right click on the completed download on the download window and select "open folder containing the download". Double click on the downloaded file "udisks2_2.0.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb" to install/upgrade. Please ensure the internet connection is on while install/upgrade. U R Done. Now open File Manager and choose any drive to mount/surf.